# Post-hoc test after GLM with binary data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binary-data, post-hoc

This is my first time posting here so apologies in advance if I have done anything incorrectly.

I have performed a binomial GLM and am now trying to perform a post-hoc test to see the significance of interactions.

I am looking at shopping choices in response to different variables. My response variable is choose (yes or no; 1/0) and my explanatory variables are label (a,b,c), price (High, Middle, Low) and category (Fresh, Dairy, Meat, Staples, Snacks).

The GLM I performed is below:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Choose2 ~ Code + Cost + Category, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = shop.data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2000  -0.6091  -0.4510  -0.2622   2.7205  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -1.7237     0.1703 -10.120  < 2e-16 ***
Codeb            -0.5550     0.1101  -5.042 4.61e-07 ***
Codec            -1.5233     0.1338 -11.382  < 2e-16 ***
CostLow           1.7766     0.1326  13.398  < 2e-16 ***
CostMiddle        0.5619     0.1454   3.863 0.000112 ***
CategoryFresh    -0.4287     0.1518  -2.824 0.004744 ** 
CategoryMeat     -0.2639     0.1707  -1.546 0.122093    
CategorySnacks   -0.5177     0.1794  -2.886 0.003897 ** 
CategoryStaples  -0.1062     0.1615  -0.658 0.510704    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3360.2  on 3741  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2960.6  on 3733  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2978.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I have performed an ANOVA:

```
> drop1(m.full, test = "Chisq")
Single term deletions

Model:
Choose2 ~ Code + Cost + Category
         Df Deviance    AIC     LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>        2960.6 2978.6                      
Code      2   3110.6 3124.6 150.033 < 2.2e-16 ***
Cost      2   3213.3 3227.3 252.723 < 2.2e-16 ***
Category  4   2975.4 2985.4  14.794  0.005148 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Which from the above I interpret that each factor in my model is significant.

I have run the glht function from the multcomp package and created the p-values for the individual factors, e.g.,:

```
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glm(formula = Choose2 ~ Code + Cost + Category, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = shop.data)

Linear Hypotheses:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Low - High == 0      1.7766     0.1326  13.398  < 1e-04 ***
Middle - High == 0   0.5619     0.1454   3.863 0.000336 ***
Middle - Low == 0   -1.2147     0.1122 -10.828  < 1e-04 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

What I would like to find, if possible, is a p-value for interaction terms. E.g I think that the interaction between cost low and label a will be significant, but I am unsure how to find p-values for this. I have performed the following:

```
glm(formula = Choose2 ~ Code * Cost, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = shop.data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0137  -0.6858  -0.4257  -0.1657   2.9309  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -1.9763     0.1754 -11.266  < 2e-16 ***
Codeb             -0.4595     0.2407  -1.909  0.05633 .  
Codec             -2.3050     0.4467  -5.160 2.47e-07 ***
CostLow            1.5783     0.2077   7.598 3.02e-14 ***
CostMiddle         0.6487     0.2002   3.241  0.00119 ** 
Codeb:CostLow      0.1354     0.2829   0.478  0.63234    
Codec:CostLow      1.0484     0.4766   2.200  0.02783 *  
Codeb:CostMiddle  -0.5682     0.3360  -1.691  0.09078 .  
Codec:CostMiddle   0.4173     0.5508   0.758  0.44863    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3360.2  on 3741  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2962.1  on 3733  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2980.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

But am struggling to interpret this in a way that I could report in my paper. How to I calculate p-values from this etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use `library(car); Anova(m.full)`. And then the *emmeans* package for post-hoc comparisons.

Comment: @SalMangiafico thank you very much! I haven't come across this one so this is very helpful

Comment: Hi, @luna_989 .  This is something that comes up all the time with R users, due to the fact that, traditionally, examples in R tend to use the `summary(model)` view of summarizing the results of a linear model, rather than the `anova(model)` view of summarizing the model.  But for routine use, `car::Anova()` and the *emmeans* package are using the most general and flexible approaches.